# jquery mobile li list view from cvs file

Tags: jquery, csv, jquery-mobile

I am working on a jquery mobile app, and I would like to take data from a csv file and use it to create the correct number of thumbnail li. I am using $.csv.toArrays to bring in the csv data.

ie

csv data

```
var data =
 {"color","URL","grade","setter","location"
  "color1","URL1","grade1","setter1","location1"}
```

I'm not sure how to go about defining a function that will take this data and generate the correct number of list items

Comment: Are you sure those aren't supposed to be square braces `[]`?

Comment: they are being imported from a csv file I'm just giving an example of my data

Comment: Yes but this isn't what would come out of `$.csv.toArrays`. The result looks more like `[['color','url','grade'],['color1','url1','grade1']]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by including a listview in your html markup within the page content:

```
<ul id="mylist" data-role="listview"></ul>
```

Then in code, assuming your csv data is actually parsed to:

```
var data=[
  ["color","URL","grade","setter","location"],
  ["color1","URL1","grade1","setter1","location1"],
  ["color2","URL2","grade2","setter2","location2"]
];
```

You want to iterate the data skipping the first line which is just column titles (`i = 1; i < data.length`), and build a string of the listitem html markup:

```
var listitems = '';
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
    listitems += '<li><a href="' + data[i][4] +'"><img src="' + data[i][1] +'"><h2>' + data[i][2] +'</h2><p>' + data[i][3] +'</p></a></li>';
}
```

Finally, append these items to the listview and tell jQM to refresh:

```
 $("#mylist").empty().append(listitems).listview("refresh");
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/mubx16h6/)**

**NOTE: you will need to adjust the listitem markup to display your data appropriately!**